# My labels are blurry in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am writing an application with small fonts in JLabels meant to be displayed on large low res screens.

I create a JLablel using this code, the JFrame has white background.

```
JLabel myJlabel=new JLabel();
myJlabel.setFont(new Font("Terminal",0,8));
myJlabel.setForeground(Color.black);
myJlabel.setText("Hamburger");
```

But it looks blurry. The image blow illustrates my problem. On the left it is from a screenshot of my application and on the right it is from the Notapad.exe with the same font and size. One if blurry and on is not.

[image]

Here is the images again enlarged and re-screen shot so you won't need to zoom to see my problem.

[image]

I need the labels in Java to be just as sharp as on the right. Is there a way to make JLabels not blurry?

Comment: i tested this code, i could not find any blurness, just increase font size,that may solve your problem

Comment: probably has something to do with graphical scaling of your application. I get this sometimes with applications on my desktop.. I need to change the properties in my short cut link.

Comment: My problem is that I can't increase the font size. I needs to be 8 points in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, as you haven't provided any code, but if you have anti-aliasing enabled, that can cause the text to be displayed like it is:

```
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on"); 
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

Try removing these (if they exist), or setting them to "off" and "false" respectively.