# Why is my java application blurry?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

This is what I wish to make
[image: what i want to make]

This is what is being showed when I run my java application. (see the text on my button and the text in text box is java)
[image: what is it being made]

I am using Eclipse Luna on Windows 7.

PS: [My labels are blurry in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906979/my-labels-are-blurry-in-java) was not of any help

```
public class DownloadManager {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField txtUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DownloadManager window = new DownloadManager();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DownloadManager() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 752, 514);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(47, 190, 629, 250);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);

        txtUrl = new JTextField();
        txtUrl.setBounds(47, 84, 391, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtUrl);
        txtUrl.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnDownload = new JButton("Download");
        btnDownload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        btnDownload.setBounds(534, 78, 99, 47);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDownload);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Solution suggested by [Swing rendering appears broken in JDK 1.8, correct in JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7) i.e. changing the energy control settings of NVIDIA GeForce 630M to maximum performance did not help.

Comment: And you think two photos is all the information we need to solve your issue?

Comment: @AliAmiri I added the whole code of class

Comment: Hello, you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7/26610279#26610279

Answer (score 4):

Use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to mitigate the artifacts shown above. The example below [nests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) one `JPanel` in another.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DownloadManager {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField txtUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DownloadManager window = new DownloadManager();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DownloadManager() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        table = new JTable() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        };
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtUrl = new JTextField(12);
        txtUrl.setColumns(10);
        JButton btnDownload = new JButton("Download");
        btnDownload.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(txtUrl);
        panel.add(btnDownload);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```